# ng-repeat takes too much time to render data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I know there are many questions already posted for the same issue but none of the solutions work in my case.

On calling a web service I get JSON response. In this JSON, there are around 2000+ objects from which I need to display data on the table. I want to display all (2000+) records in the table and Yes, I cannot limit or paginate, need to display it on a single page (I know it's stupid but it's the business requirement). I don't need sorting or searching.

Data transfer is about 2MB and the request completes in about 2-4 secs approx. but it takes around 10-15 secs to data render on the page.

Now, what I am looking for is either speed ng-repeat binding things up (if possible) or display the data as soon as I receive it and keep on adding it until all rows are displayed.

Check out the code below :

HTML

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped cf">
<thead style="color: #333;">
<tr>
<td>Asset Name</td>
<td>Date/ Time</td>
<td>Location</td>
<td>Ignition</td>
<td>Speed</td>
<td>Heading</td>
<td>Direction</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="cols in tableData">
<td>{{ cols.aN }}</td>
<td>{{ cols.dT }}</td>
<td>{{ cols.Lat }}, {{ cols.Lon }}</td>
<td>{{ cols.I }}</td>
<td>{{ cols.S }}</td>
<td>{{ cols.H }}</td>
<td>{{ cols.D }}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
var ignition_text = '';
var lat = '';
var lon = '';
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].ignition = 1) {
        ignition_text = "On";
    } else {
        ignition_text = "Off";
    }
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.tableData.push({
            aN: name,
            dT: data[i].eventUTCTime,
            Lat: data[i].latitudeDegrees,
            Lon: data[i].longitudeDegrees,
            I: ignition_text,
            S: data[i].speedMPH,
            H: data[i].longitudeDegrees,
            D: data[i].latitudeDegrees
        });
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this html page routed from another page?

Comment: @Aravind nope it's not

Comment: :( Who can read 2000 lines of data at once

Comment: @USER_8675309 I know that's what I am wondering. Actually, this is a monthly report, user will download it but need to display this on the page as well.

Comment: your markup of the page is loaded but the content comes after the complete load?

Comment: You shouldn't need to call $scope.$apply since the data is being pushed onto an object that Angular knows about.  It's also a pretty expensive operation.

Answer (score 2):

You probably wont need `$scope.$apply` at all. And even if you need it, you should only use it once you pushed all data to the table. Otherwise, every added entry will force an digest-cycle. Just build your array and assign the finished array to the scope-variable. Then angular will only build the table once.

Depending on the nature of your variable `name` you may be able to eliminate the array building as well and just use the data you are downloading. Apart from `name`you just use that data anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a plunk that has a similar data size but loads much faster http://plnkr.co/edit/I4rN1ZMaR3e1mbcsJ9Ka. If you were to make a quick plunk I could use your data and edit your code but from the looks you just need the main assignment to the scope without the apply for the data and add a track by to the ng-repeat. SN: You would want to manipulate your data inside the for loop then do the assignment to the scope.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].ignition = 1) {
        ignition_text = "On";
    } else {
        ignition_text = "Off";
    }
    }
    $scope.tableData=data;
```

JS

```
 $http.get("largeData.json").then(function(response) {
    vm.test = response.data;
  });
```

HTML

```
<tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in main.test track by $index ">
        <td>{{ value.ask }}</td>
        <td>{{ value.bid }}</td>
        <td>{{ value.volume_btc }}, {{ value.volume_percent }}</td>
        <td>{{ value.last }}</td>
        <td>{{ value.timestamp }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```